# segmentation fault in virtual method invokation

Tags: segmentation-fault, clang, llvm

clang uses the following scheme to define a concrete type in llvm ir:

```
%"mytype" = type {virtual_method_types, field_types, super_types}
```

and in order to call a virtual method (e.g. virtual int f(){}) the following scheme is used:

```
%0 = load %"mytype"** %this
%1 = bitcast %"mytype"* %0 to i32 (%"mytype"*)***
%vtable = load i32 (%"mytype"*)*** %1
%method = getelementptr inbounds i32 (%"mytype"*)** %vtable, i64 0 (index of f() in vt)
%ld = load i32 (%"mytype"*)** %method 
%call = call i32 (%"mytype"*)* %ld (%"mytype"* %0)
```

However, if the following scheme was used instead, what should be changed in the above code to prevent seg fault?

```
 %"mytype" = type {field_types, super_types, virtual_method_types}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line gets the pointer at the start of the object, which is the vptr (pointer to the virtual table):

```
%1 = bitcast %"mytype"* %0 to i32 (%"mytype"*)***
```

If you place the vptr at the end of the object instead, this code would need to change to use an `extractvalue` on `%0` to get the pointer to the correct location of the vptr (or alternatively a `getelementptr` on `%this`, but as you anyway need to load `%this`, it doesn't really help). For instance, if the vptr will be the 12th field in `%"mytype"`, you'll need something like:

```
%1 = extractvalue %"mytype" %0, 12
```